# How to read and parse PHP objects in J2ME

Tags: java, php, web-services, java-me

I am creating **J2ME mobile application** that communicates with **PHP Web Service** app. I was successful to connect my app to the Web Service. What is the standard way to provide data from my PHP Web Service to my app?

I have array of query result in PHP, how can I send this result to my app for **ease of parsing** in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the typical way developers do it, is to serialize their objects.
In other words, transform their objects into simple text.

If you have a PHP Array, you would simply loop through and echo out the values, with whatever delimiter you choose.

Then you just read that text from your MIDlet.